# Nginx conf with php-fpm alias not working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, kohana

i cant get the kohana aplication working.

Server specs: ubuntu 14.04, nginx, php7.0-fpm

I have the following structure:

build: (static website)
,server: (php-kohana application)

```
|-- build
|   |-- fonts
|   |-- images
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- scripts
|   `-- styles
|-- server
|   `-- cms
|       |-- application
|       |-- database
|       |-- index.php
|       |-- install.php.bkp
|       |-- media
|       |-- modules
|       |-- system
|       `-- vendor
```

And the following nginx conf:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

root /srv/www/build/;
location = /{
}
location /server/cms/{
    alias /srv/www/server/cms/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

When i access / i can see the static website,

but when i access /server/cms/ i dont see any errors, only a blank page, no logs in /var/log/nginx/error.log

What can i be missing, why i am not getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP location block has no directory specified. So, it means that when going to http://www.example.com/index.php, nginx will try to search `/srv/www/build/index.php`, which does not exist.

I don't know how the Kohana application is designed and how it should be deployed. If you want to show `/srv/www/server/cms/index.php` when user goes into http://www.example.com/, you need to use this PHP `location` block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    alias /srv/www/server/cms/;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
}
```